# localizing json in iso format to local date

Tags: javascript, json, date

I have a json response with a date in iso format. I am trying to convert it to a date format and localize it for Swedish.
I think I'm close, but I'm missing a step in converting. I get 'invalid date' in the console for the following code:

```
var callback = function (text, video) {
    parsedData = JSON.parse(text);
    var sortedParsedData = _.sortBy(parsedData, 'publishedAt')
    initVideo(sortedParsedData,listEl);
    console.log('parsed', sortedParsedData);


      var videoDate = sortedParsedData[0].publishedAt;
      var localDate = new Date(videoDate);
      console.log(localDate.toLocaleDateString('se-SE'));   //this results in 'Invalid Date'

}

function getAjax(callback, video) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback(JSON.stringify([{
            "id": "vid1",
            "title": "Lorem ipsum",
            "description": "This is a great day for a workout",
            "author": "Lars Ohlsson",
            "publishedAt": "2018-05-12T10:11:05+99:00",
            "imageUrl": "img/as.png",
            "thumbnailUrl": "img/as-500-150x150.png",
            "views": 48224,
            "tags": [
                "workout",
                "friends"
            ],
            "contentUrl": "video/tears-of-steel-battle-clip-medium.mp4",
            "thumb-url": "#"
        }, {
            ...
        }]), video)
    }, 100)
}
```

Comment: The offset of "+99:00" is invalid, so any parser consistent with [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) will return an invalid date (with a time value of NaN). The offset range must be from 00 to 24.

Comment: you're right. That fixed it.